# How do I use the output of Range as the input arguments of another function?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

If I enter `LCM[1,2,3,4,5]` 60 is returned.
if I enter `LCM[Range[5]]` {1,2,3,4,5} is returned.

I think I understand *why* it returns a list. (because it is treating the list as one argument?)

How can I use the output from the Range function act as individual arguments in the LCM function? How do I change `LCM[Range[5]]` so that it too returns 60?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Apply`, or its short form `@@`:

```
LCM @@ Range[5]
(* 60 *)
```